# Create Observable from Ionic 2 form input element change event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to create an Observable from an Ionic 2 form element.

There's a handy function for events, [Observable.fromEvent](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md), but I've the reference to the form element from the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html), not the real element. Surely I can grab from the DOM, but I suppose there's a better approach.

## Current status

I declare form elements using Form Buidler service:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  elem1: new FormControl('elem1'),
  elem2: new FormControl('elem2'),
  elem3: new FormControl('elem3'),
  elem4: new FormControl('elem3')
});

this.formInputElem1: AbstractControl = this.myForm.get('elem1');
```

Usually I would do:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.formInputElem, 'ionChange');
```

But `this.formInputElem` but first `Observable.formEvent` param should be EventTargetLike and form elem is an AbstactControl.

I've tried to cast `formInputElem1` to [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) and check if any function return the DOM elem or a EventTargetLike with no luck.

[EventTargetLike](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L89) is "The DOMElement, event target, Node.js, EventEmitter, NodeList or HTMLCollection to attach the event handler to."

So, how to get an observable from a Ionic 2 input form element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just discovered that form elements have the [valueChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#valueChanges-anchor) property that returns an Observable:

> valueChanges : Observable Emits an event every time the value of
>   the control changes, in the UI or programmatically.

Comment: Was just about to post that!